# How to encrypt Lua codes

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to protect my Lua codes on my project, I'm using Corona SDK.

I saw some lua files being obfuscated like this one

https://github.com/ChartBoost/corona-sdk/blob/master/ChartboostSDK/chartboost.lua

Is there any application to protect my source code?

Comment: Why protect source code?

Comment: I want to share a lua sdk on a ads network, but the links are exposed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file you mentioned is not encrypted: it's just precompiled bytecode for Lua 5.1. It can be read with `luac -l -p` (not in source form but in VM instructions, which are probably enough to reconstruct the source). If you want to reconstruct the source, try [LuaDec for Lua 5.1](http://luaforge.net/projects/luadec51/).

You can precompile your code using `luac` or `string.dump`.

Comment: How do I compile LuaDec?

Comment: I am able to produce luac.out, how can I require it to my project?

Comment: @Ramyle, luac.out can be loaded directly into Lua with `require` or `dofile`.