# I Need to Decrypt one LUA file

Tags: lua

I have main.lua file that was encrypted like this...

[Image of Encryption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAZ9O.jpg)

Need help to decrypt this file and tell me how to do it i don't have much knowledge about this..

Comment: why would you post a screenshot of text where you can post text?

Comment: What do you see if you replace `load` with `print`?

Comment: let's start with what you tried. What is the first thing you tried and didnt work? show us the code you wrote.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I de-obfuscate a Lua script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66121229/how-do-i-de-obfuscate-a-lua-script)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already well covered in other SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148752/how-to-decrypt-lua-bytecode) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915486/how-to-encrypt-lua-codes), so start with those.

The short answer is: it's likely not encrypted, but stored as Lua bytecode for obfuscation pusposes. You can read/convert the bytecode (and figure out what the script does), but not without knowledge of Lua scripting. Nobody on SO would do this for you.

Comment: That doesn't look like bytecode to me. Look what the escapes decode to.

Comment: The escapes don't look like a lua code to me. If it's an unmodified `load`, then it's either a Lua source code or its bytecode. If it's a modified `load` function, then it can be anything.

Comment: The first character is `\98`. Lua bytecode always starts with `\27`. That looks to me like Lua source code with random variable names.